# como sustituir el = por un / en la url php

Tags: php

hola buenos dias tengo la siguiente pregunta .. en una url sale de la siguiente manera

```html
localhost/prueba/informacion.php?informar=informacion-necesaria
```

como puedo cambiar ese = por un / ? quedando de la siguiente manera

```html
localhost/prueba/informacion.php?informar/informacion-necesaria
```

o mejor aun

```html
localhost/prueba/informacion.php/informar/informacion-necesaria
```

Comment: mod_rewrite y htaccess: https://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/

Comment: Toma en cuenta que ahi estas modificando en gran forma la comunicación con tu servidor que captura la petición, tal vez te sea de ayuda leer este documento: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: con el htaccess lo eh intentado pero no me resulta

Answer (score 0):

Ser url-friendly o tener urls semánticas o amigables por lo general requieren considerar algunas cosas adicionales.

En el primer ejemplo que comentas:

```
http://localhost/prueba/informacion/informar/informacion-necesaria
```

Lo que estas realizando es una llamada al archivo /prueba/informacion.php y pasándole un parámetro via query string, `informar` con el valor `informacion-necesaria`, este parámetro debe ser leído y procesado por el archivo `informacion.php`

Para poder procesar este mismo request pero desde una url de tipo

```
http://localhost/prueba/informacion/informar/informacion-necesaria
```

Lo que necesitas es construir un ruteador de urls, es decir en tu servidor web (Apache, Nginx o si es php > 7.x podrías hacerlo con PHP), seria de esta manera:

```
http://localhost/prueba/informacion/informar/informacion-necesaria
```

**¿Qué es un ruteador de urls?**

Es una porción de codigo destinado a capturar el request http e interpretar él url path (informar/informacion-necesaria) para posteriormente llamar al archivo o componente que realizara el procesamiento del request.

Para consultar la url solicitada desde php podrías usar:

```
<?php

$url_requested = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

// parsear este atributo para separar los componentes de la solicitud

?>
```

> Algunos frameworks de php te ayudan con esto.

Comment: pero coloco eso asi yy ya?  porque yo cree esa url if(isset($_GET['servicios'])){
  $dato = $_GET['servicios'];
$servicios = $bd->query("SELECT * from servicios where titulourl = '$dato'");
$roww=mysqli_fetch_array($servicios);

}

en mi tabla d la bd tengo un campo llamado titulo url q es el q uso en ese get

Comment: No, era un ejemplo debes construir la lógica del router y levantar un servidor web no podes hacerlo con un solo archivo .php nuevamente te sugiero usar algún framework que ya te resuelva la logica del router.

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa seria usar nginx rules, para interpretar el request original y redirigirla a la ruta pre existente.

en el archivo .conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ~^pmstrk\.mercadoli([bv])re\.com$;

    location ~ /informacion/informar/(.*) {
         proxy_pass http://localhost?informacion=$1;
    }
}
```